# branch exists locally and on github, but cannot push

Tags: git, github

First, I apologise for having such a noob question; but git seems to be something that's existed forever, so all the documentation seems to assume some knowledge. I am currently reading Gitpro to see if a solution exists, but I thought I'd also ask here.

Note: some names changed, but all formatting is correct

So, I have a github repository named fitnet at https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet
this has three branches: `master`, `dev` and `staging`, with the following urls.

I have verified on the github site that these exist.

```
master:         github.com/Jose/Fitnet/Tree/master
fitnetdev:      github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnetdev
fitnet_Staging: github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnet_staging
```

locally, I have these branches:

- fitnet_staging
- fitnetdev
- master

I have these remotes locally: (via git remote -v)

```
Master               https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet (fetch)
Master               https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet (push)
fitnet_staging       https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnet_staging (fetch)
fitnet_staging       https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnet_staging (push)
fitnetdev            https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnetdev (fetch)
fitnetdev            https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnetdev (push)
```

I created all these branches on the command line using git Init on c:\fitnet

however, when I try:

```
git push fitnet_staging fitnet_staging
```

, I get an error that says:

```
C:\Fitnet>git push fitnet_staging fitnet_staging
fatal: https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet/tree/fitnet_staging/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I am sure that I am missing something very elementary here that is old hand to all of you git experts, so again, I apologise for asking such a question.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add individual branches as remotes. In git, one repository will be equivalent to one remote, and vice versa. One repository can contain multiple branches in itself, and all off them are accessed using the same remote.

So, to solve your issue

1. Clear all the remotes from your current repository. For this, you can edit the `.git/config` file within the local repository, and delete all entries corresponding tagged like `[remote ""]`
2. Next, in your local repo, use the following command to add a remote github to your local repo:

   ```
   git remote add github https://github.com/Jose/Fitnet
   ```
3. Finally, you can push to github from your local repo like:

   ```
   git push github fitnet_staging
   ```

Comment: Ah. Now I get it. Remotes are just location pointers to the github repo, and git push [remote name] [branch name] is what I wanted. Thank you very much. I am used to VSTF and the paradigms were different. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2052652 Cool! Confusing branches with repos is a common mistake for beginners in git :)